# Textbox text returns nothing when fired from within updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

This is my code

```
<form class="subscribe">
                                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updSub" runat="server">
                                                <ContentTemplate>
                                                    <div class="col-three-forth">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email"></asp:TextBox>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-one-third">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btn btn" Text="Subscribe Now" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </ContentTemplate>
                                                <Triggers>
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
                                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtEmail" />
                                                </Triggers>
                                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                        </form>
```

and this is my code behine

```
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Email(txtEmail.Text);
        }
```

txtEmail.Text always returns empty string no matter what was in the textbox!

how can I make it read the text in txtEmail field?

Comment: define `EventName="Click"` for `ControlID="btnSubmit"`

Comment: @viveknuna code goes into the click function but it does not get the value of the textbox txtEmail anyway I added EventName="Click" but still the same